# How to deal with optionally arguments in design?

Tags: python

Sometimes I have a function like this:

```
def my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3):
  pass
```

In which either one or two are optional and it makes sense. However it doesn't make sense for all the 3 arguments to be absent at the same time. It seems I have two ways to deal with:

1. Just use one 'my_func' and leave all the 3 arguments optional. Inside the function, I can do a check:

   ```
   def my_func(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):

    if arg1 is None and arg2 is None and arg3 is None:
       raise ValueError("Invalid arguments. Cant be None at the same time!")
   ```
2. Split the my_func() into 2 or three functions which requires at least arg to be present:

   ```
   def my_func_1(arg1, arg2=None, arg3=None):
     pass

   def my_func_2(arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
     pass
   ```

When the number of arguments increases, things get more complicated. For splitting, the implementations are simpler, but potentially have redundant code. For one single func, the user interface isn't very clear, and the implementation will be more complex, and it needs a lot of if ... else checking.

I personally prefer the first 1-function approach. Is there a good practice for this situation?

Comment: Have you read about ```*args``` and ```**kwargs```?

Comment: *args requires at least one arg to be mandatory?

Comment: @marlon I think imposing conditions on that should be more flexible and easier in your case

Comment: No, but you can test `if len(args) == 0:`

Comment: 'imposing conditions on that', what's 'on that'?

Comment: If you like the first version and it gives you the desired results - I say use it... There is nothing wrong with it and it's also very common to do something similar with `argparse` arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to perform this check on more than just one function, you can write a decorator to handle the arg checking.

```
from functools import wraps

def not_all_none(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cond_args = all(a is None for a in args)
        cond_kw = all(v is None for v in kwargs.values())

        if cond_args and cond_kw:
            raise ValueError("All arguments cannot be None at the same time.")
        
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@not_all_none
def my_func(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    return True
```

This requires at least one argument to not be `None`.

```
my_func()
# raises:
ValueError: All arguments cannot be None at the same time.

my_func(0)
# returns:
True

my_func(arg2=100)
# returns:
True
```

You can use this for any functions that requires at least one non-None input.

```
@not_all_none
def other_func(a, b=0, c=None, d=None, e=None, f=None):
    return True

other_func(None)
# returns:
True

other_func(None, None)
# raises
ValueError: All arguments cannot be None at the same time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check that some required arg is `not None` in the beginning of your function.

```py
def my_func_1(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    if arg2 is None and arg3 is None:
        raise ValueError("arg2 or arg3 must be set")
```

You can also use `any()`

```py
if not any((arg1, arg2, arg3)):
    raise ValueError("one of arg1,arg2,arg3 must be set")
```

Comment: Your first version doesn't allow a call like `my_func_1(arg2 = 1)` because `arg1` is a required positional argument.

Comment: Ah the initial question was a bit wonky .. they may also have an XY problem and want `**kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
def my_func_1(args1, **kwargs):
```

Or (if you don't want keyword arguments):

```py
def my_func_1(args1, *args):
```

Then you ensure at the very least you have 1 argument, however you can also put more than 3 in total, that's the only downside here...

Comment: Why not just `my_func(**kwargs)`? This way the user can pass any combination

Comment: Because it has to have at least 1 argument (that's what I understood at least)

Comment: It has to be at least 1, as in `len(kwargs) > 0`, but it doesn't have to be `arg1`... Maybe I'm overcomplicating but it's how I understand it. What if the user wants to pass `arg2` and `arg3`?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, yes, any one can be optional, not necessarily 'arg1'. Maybe just my_func(*arg) or my_func(**arg).

Comment: I mean from the proposal with split option in OP's question, I figured `arg1` is the mandatory one

Comment: @Tomerikoo, would this look weird for users when args can be completely optional? Internally, I can do a check to make sure at least one is required.

Comment: @marlon this is starting to feel like an XY-problem. Maybe if you gave a bit more context about the **use** of `my_func` we would have better insights.

Comment: I mean when you do `def my_func(arg, *args)` it won't matter - everything becomes positional then. If you want with keyword you cannot make argument name ambiguous from the function point of view (i.e. that you have 1 mandatory argument, which can take any name)

Comment: @Tomerikoo What's XY-problem?

Comment: @marlon Sorry, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?r=SearchResults&s=1|681.4541 TL;DR when you have problem X and think Y is the solution and ask about Y instead of X